# Amending Font Size Without Affecting Other Classes

Tags: html, css

Please see my code below:

HTML =>

```
<header>
    <div class="menuWrap">
        <a href="" class="menuItem" title="Home">Home</a>
        <a href="" class="menuItem" title="About">About</a>
        <a href="" class="logoItem" title="Adam McCann">AM</a>
        <a href="" class="menuItem" title="Work">Work</a>
        <a href="" class="menuItem" title="Contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS =>

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E6E6E6;
}

.menuWrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.menuItem {
    line-height: 80px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
    color: #1DC0CE;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    font-size: 25px;
    -o-transition: .2s;
    -ms-transition: .2s;
    -moz-transition: .2s;
    -webkit-transition: .2s;
    transition: .2s;            
}

.logoItem {
    line-height: 80px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15%;
    background-color: #1DC0CE;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    font-size: 25px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #1DC0CE;
    -o-transition: .2s;
    -ms-transition: .2s;
    -moz-transition: .2s;
    -webkit-transition: .2s;
    transition: .2s;        
}
```

When I am increasing the font-size for 'logoItem' the 'menuItem' elements position is moving (the text is moving down the page)

Any tips on how to stop this!?

Comment: Increase the width maybe?

Comment: i tested your fiddle with 76px font size and menu items are still there not moving down!

Answer (score 1):

Give them a uniform height and ensure it's large enough to work for both sizes:

```
#menuWrap a {
    display:inline-block;
    height:30px;
}
```

You should probably get rid of the `line-height` declaration as well.